# jsf component.valid first time entering the page

Tags: validation, jsf

I'm displaying a small icon next to input fields when validation did not pass. I can do it but I was hoping for a better solution than what I have currently:

```
<p:inputText ... binding="#{myfield}">
    <f:validator binding="#{myfieldValidator}"/>
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="myfieldFeedback"/>
</p:inputText>


<h:panelGroup id="myfieldFeedback">
    <div class="failedIndicator colorRed" jsf:rendered="#{myFieldvalidator.isIndicatorvisible.myFieldfailed}">!</div>
    <div class="successIndicator" jsf:rendered="#{myFieldValidator.isIndicatorVisible.myFieldSuccess}">v</div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

With inside my validator:

```
    private Map<String, Boolean> isIndicatorVisible;
    isIndicatorVisible.put("myFieldSuccess", false);//if validation succeeds goes to true
    isIndicatorVisible.put("myFieldFailed", false);// opposite of above
```

I'm hoping for a better solution (that doesn't use a map) like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="myfieldFeedback">
    <div class="#{myfield.valid ? 'successIndicator' : 'noDisplay'}">v</div>
    <div class="#{myfield.valid ? 'noDisplay' : 'failedIndicator colorRed'}">!</div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The field is valid upon entenring for the first time the dialog in which the form is displayed. Thus there is a valid feedback which is displayed I do not wish to have.

Comment: Can you try <h:panelGroup id="myfieldFeedback" rendered="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 3)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thus want to make sure the conditions are only evaluated during a postback request, not during an initial (GET) request. You can check that by [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback--).

```
<h:panelGroup id="myfieldFeedback">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.postback}">
        <div class="...">v</div>
        <div class="...">!</div>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, even though I won't use that since my dialog is dynamic. I guess I'll just put a counter in my bean or something. It's good to know none the less.

Comment: If the initial request is is in turn also a postback by itself (e.g. because it's inside a dialog), then you'd alter the condition in the `rendered` attribute accordingly, e.g. check which form and/or button was submitted/pressed.

Comment: That sounds better than my map indd